# Auto populate submodule version to parent module

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am running windows with git `version 1.8.1.msysgit.1`

I have two seperate repos (1 and 2 for example, both maintained by me) and repo 2 is added to repo 1 as a submodule (as a copy). Then I change something in the submodule and push to remote. If i check the version of the submodule (repo 2) as a seperate repo on remote I get the newest hash. But then If check the version of the submodule on remote its still the old hash. Can't I automate this? (remote for me being github)

Comment: If you push to a remote repository the other should pull the changes.

Comment: I can't get the parent repo on remote to show the new version number. I push the submodule (from either location, as submodule or independent module) to the remote. Its repo get updated with the new hash number. The parent repo still shows `a.submodule@oldhash`. If I try to pull the parent repo from remote it says everything up to date. I could make a diagramm for clarification if needed.

Comment: Everything *is* up to date in the parent repo. The parent repo just tracks which version the submodule is at. If you do a `git status` in the parent, you should see the submodule say there are "new commits." You must `git add submodulename` to tell the parent repo to update its reference to the submodule's current commit, then `commit` it. Just as you have to `add` and `commit` changes in your repo, you must do the same to track changes in the submodule.

Comment: Ok thank you. I got it to work like this. Still very confused with submodules. There is only a small link between parent and submodule, which seems to be the .gitmodules file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a submodule just tells git via the `.gitmodules` and `.git/config` files that a particular folder in your repo should be treated as a separate entity, which contains an entire other repo from somewhere else. You can think of the entire folder as a file that gets versioned along with everything else, but what you're actually versioning in your repo is which commit that particular repo is on.

Let's say you've made a repo with submodule like this:

```
git init (or clone) a repo
git submodule add otherrepo path/to/otherrepo
```

Here's the basic workflow with submodules:

```
# either make some changes to the submodule yourself...
cd otherrepo
make some changes
git add --update .
git commit -m'Change some things'

# ...or pull some in from elsewhere
cd otherrepo
git pull

# now out in your repo, track those changes
cd ..
git add otherrepo
git commit -m'Point to latest commit in otherrepo'
```

Let's forget submodules for a minute. You could make changes to a file in your repo, but never add/commit them. That file would always work going forward, because when it broke against changes elsewhere in the repo, you'd fix it. It would match what was going on in the rest of `HEAD`. You wouldn't be able to roll back anywhere, though. That file would be kept up to date, but the history of your repo wouldn't properly be tracking where it was at certain times.

This is how it is with submodules. You can think of the entire submodule as a single file. No matter what the changes are that are committed into it, the only thing your repo cares about - the only thing it's allowed to care about - is what commit your repo says is the current one in the submodule. It can't reach in and do things with particular files, so all it can do is keep track of which commit the whole submodule is on, so that's what it does. Just as with the file in the earlier example, though, you must carefully keep the submodule at the right commit, and tell your repo which commit that is, or your history won't have the right idea about where to roll the submodule back to when you go back in time in your own repo.

You must add/commit it along with your other files to tell your repo's history "This is where this submodule should be right now." If you *don't* do this, then every new commit on your repo re-adds in wherever the repo was the last time it was added and committed in your repo. If you move the submodule forward a few commits, or if you pull in some submodule commits, and you want those new commits to be part of the history of your repo right now, then you need to add and commit the submodule in your repo to update the commit it thinks is the current one.

Comment: Wow thanks for taking the time and explaining it properly to me. I would offer you a beer if stack had this feature^^