# Automatically run the workflow on the main repo when a submodule repo changes

Tags: github, workflow, github-actions

I have a repository that has a submodule repo, I want to run the workflow of the main repo in case of any submodule repo changes.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511616/auto-populate-submodule-version-to-parent-module

Comment: How would the submodule change? Would it be manually? You could use a `paths` subtype in your workflow `on` trigger to run only when the submodule files are updated.

Comment: I mean if i do a change to the submodule repo, I want the workflow on the main repo to start running. I tried to use paths and give it a path of my submodule 'dir1/submoduledir ', but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I should switch to the master branch.

```
cd otherrepo/
git checkout master
```

After making changes to the submodule repository, I should push these changes first.

```
cd otherrepo/
** making changes – Editing README.md file **
git add README.md
git commit -m 'editing README.md'
git push origin master
```

Then, push the main repository.

```
cd ..
git add otherrepo
git commit -m 'editing otherrepo submodule'
git push origin master
```